# how do i add or increase a numeric value in an input text field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm using this jquery calculation plugin: http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm

i'm using the sum example.

in my version, i'm dynamically inserting values into fields and recalculating and all works well, but so far i have just been inserting new values into empty fields.

now in a separate action i want to increase the value of one of the fields that has been previously filled by a value and then recalculate again.

i setup a fiddle with what i'm trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/rEQnY/1/

there's a dropdown with options.  each option has a numeric value.

now as an example lets just pick a field at random.  lets say that 3rd field that has a number "1" in it.

when i select one of the dropdown values, i want that 3rd field with a number 1 in it to increase by that much, and then the total sum box should also increase by that much.

in the javascript i started with listening to a change in the dropdown box, but what do i insert in between there?

maybe i can grab the selected value like this:

```
$('#numbers').val();
```

but then how do i add it to the other field?

update:

how do i fix this new version?

http://jsfiddle.net/rEQnY/8/

i want 2 different fields to add value to another field.

if dropdown 1 (by itself) adds 2 to 3rd input text box, 3rd input text box should become 3.

if dropdown 2 (by itself) adds 2 to 3rd input text box, 3rd input text box should become 3.

if 2 is selected in both dropdowns, then 4 should be added to 3rd input text box and become 5.

if either dropdown 1 or dropdown 2 is reset, meaning "pick one" is selected, then the 3rd input text box should be subtracted by 2, making it 3.

as you can see in my example, only one dropdown adds to the field.  can be either or, but not both.  i want both to be able to add to it and take away from it when the default "pick one" is selected.

Comment: You know about `$('#numbers').val(123);` right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#otherField').val(Number($('#numbers').val())+1);
```

**Update**

HTML

```
<p>
<select id="numbers" name="numbers" class="numbers">
      <option value="">pick one</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      </select>
</p>
<p>
<select id="morenumbers" name="morenumbers" class="numbers">
      <option value="">pick one</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      </select>
</p>
```

jQuery

```
$(".numbers").change(function() {
            //grab selected value and add it to the 3rd text field
            //so if 2 is selected, the field with 1 becomes 3 and the total sum becomes 12
            var first;
            var second;
            var initial = 1;
            if($('#morenumbers').val() == '')
                first = 0;
            else
                first = Number($('#morenumbers').val());
            if($('#numbers').val() == '')
                second = 0;
            else
                second = Number($('#numbers').val());
            $('#third').val(first+second+initial);
            $("input[name^=sum]").sum("keyup", "#totalSum");
        });
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/rEQnY/9/

Comment: this is the first thing i tried and it worked.  thanks.  example: http://jsfiddle.net/rEQnY/3/

Comment: @leoarce Please mark this answer as accepted if it solved your issue.  Also upvote answers that are helpful.  Thanks

Comment: what does that 2nd example do?

Comment: Same thing its just adding a number from another field instead of `1`

Comment: @leoarce you don't need to modify your HTML at all, and your question didn't specify anything about being able to do so. If that was the case, in future please mention all details when asking questions.

Comment: +1 doesn't actually add 1.  the example fiddle proves that.  it adds the value of the option that was selected.  so what does +1 do in this scenario?  just a call to do adding math instead of subtraction or multiplication?

Comment: @leoarce also you don't need to use the `Number()` method at all as this will add unnecessary time to your code. Please see my answer for a fully working script which doesn't require HTML change nor does it require any extra methods.

Comment: @leoarce what is wrong with the fiddle you posted above saying it was working?

Comment: i updated my question and made new fiddle.  neither answer addresses what i'm really trying to do.

Comment: @leoarce please check my updated Answer and fiddle.  Please mark as accepted and up vote if this was helpful to you.

Comment: it answers the question but doesn't work in my application.  i'm going to have to ask the question again and differently in a separate s.o. question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
// On selected option change...
$("#numbers").change(function() {
    var 
        // Get the selected value as an integer
        value = +$(this).val(),

        // Get the third input field
        $thirdInput = $('input[name^="sum"]:nth-child(3)')
    ;

    // Increase the third input field's value by the selected option value
    $thirdInput.val(+$thirdInput.val() + value);

    // Recalculate the sum
    $("input[name^=sum]").sum("keyup", "#totalSum");
});
```

[**Working JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rEQnY/5/).

Here we're using a [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) to convert the value of the inputs and the drop down to an integer.

---

**Edit**: Further requirement made in comments:

> if the dropdown is changed from a numbered value to the "pick one" option, i need the addition to be retracted and go back to it's previous state.

For this we can declare a new global variable which is set to the initial value of the third text field:

```
var thirdSumValue = 1;
```

Then use this in our drop down's `change` event:

```
$thirdInput.val(thirdSumValue + value);
```

[**Updated JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rEQnY/6/).

Alternatively instead of hard coding its default value you can simply set it to the value of the text field on load:

```
var thirdSumValue = +$('input[name^="sum"]:nth-child(3)').val();
```

This will reflect any default HTML values prior to the JavaScript being loaded.

**[Final JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rEQnY/7/)**.

Comment: uhm.  the previous example was manipulating multiple fields, which is not what i was trying to do, but it seems to be fixed.  perhaps you're right that this adding method is better than the other concatenating method.

Comment: further testing shows it's not what i'm trying to do.  if the dropdown is changed from a numbered value to the "pick one" option, i need the addition to be retracted and go back to it's previous state.  the other answer seems to do that.

Comment: @leoarce in that case you simply need to save the initial value. For this I've created a new variable, `thirdSumValue` at the top of the JavaScript code which is set to 1. This is then used within the change event: http://jsfiddle.net/rEQnY/6/

Comment: since this app is going to grow, not sure going back to a set value will work.  for example, if i add another dropdown with other values, i want that 2nd drop down to add to that same field too.  now if "2" is picked from first dropdown, making that 3rd field "3", then in second drop down "2" is picked again, the third field should go from 3 to 5, but if the 2nd dropdown goes to the default "pick one" option, then the 3rd field should go back to "3", not "1".

Comment: @leoarce in your JSFiddle there is only one drop down.